# Mysql default value for new records only

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set a default value for new records only in a mysql column?

I want all rows before today to be null if nothing has been entered, but any new rows added after today to be a specific string if nothing has be entered for that column.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can create a new AutoIncrement column but not make it required so that the previous records keep a null value.

Comment: @AndréFecteau I don't think so. MySQL will refuse to create an auto-increment column that is nullable or not a primary key.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you are right, sorry about that. Just tried it on my own MySQL instance and it says the AI column must be a key.

Answer (score 2):

Search in all rows in the table and check if the specific column is empty, if yes set it to null.

```
UPDATE tablename SET column = CASE column WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE column END
```

For future entries you can add to your table a Default Constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER column SET DEFAULT 'specific string'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I do think this answer might help other folks.

```
ALTER TABLE object_table_name ADD `value` INT NULL;
ALTER TABLE object_table_name MODIFY COLUMN `value` INT DEFAULT 0;
```

Doing it this way will only impact newly inserted records, this code did not work for me

```
ALTER TABLE object_table_name ADD  `value` INT DEFAULT 0
```

I'm using MySQL 5.6